# classic asp includes not working on IIS7.5 when parent paths is disabled

Tags: asp-classic, include, iis-7.5

I am migrating a classic asp website from a Windows server running an old IIS to a Windows2008-2 server with IIS7.5 and running classic asp.

This new server does not have parent paths enabled (and they won't turn it on, and I can't get access to IIS control panel - as I am sharing the server with others).

So I am left with trying to find a way to re-code the includes that used to use a relative path to get to a sister directory.

Here is my setup:

I use their free shared ssl and both these files need to be accessed securely (the secure path is: https://ssl5.ssllock.net/mysite.com/)

I have an an .asp file located at: /SMPSECR/my-inc.asp

I have a another .asp file located at: /PBB/my-test.asp

Inside of my-test.asp, I want to include my-inc.asp

I used to use this format: #include file="../smpsecr/my-inc.asp", but since IIS6 that doesn’t work anymore (as I mentioned earlier parent paths are automatically disabled and my hosting company won't enabled it for security reasons as I am on a shared server).

I read somewhere that you can use virtual instead of file, but even that didn’t work for me.

Here are the 11 different include tests I have tried from inside of my-test.asp and failed for each one:

```
<!--#include file="https://ssl5.ssllock.net/mysite.com/smpsecr/my-inc.asp"-->
<!--#include file="/smpsecr/my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include file="smpsecr/my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include virtual="/smpsecr/my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include virtual="\smpsecr\my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include virtual="smpsecr/my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include virtual="smpsecr\my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include file=\\n5200-2\iis7_www\f\s\mysite.com\www\smpsecr\my-inc.asp"--> 
<!--#include virtual=\\n5200-2\iis7_www\f\s\mysite.com\www\smpsecr\my-inc.asp"-->
<!--#include file="//n5200-2/iis7_www/f/s/mysite.com/www/smpsecr/my-inc.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="//n5200-2/iis7_www/f/s/mysite.com/www/smpsecr/my-inc.asp"-->
```

Can anyone give me another include format that could work with my setup.. ie: when trying to include from a different directory (up one level and then down one level - in other words accessing a 'sister' directory.  Going from /PBB to /smpsecr)?

Thanks,
SunnyOz

Comment: `<!--#include file="../smpsecr/my-inc.asp"--> ` works?

Comment: @statosdotcom, no it doesn't work with parent path disabled.  That was the original way I coded it on the original server with older IIS.  IIS7.5 (with parent path disabled) won't allow you to start the path with ../ or even just /

Comment: I am sorry, you've already said it. Please forgive me.

Comment: Infortunately, accessing "sister directories" literally means *Go To Up Level > Then > Find another children folder". The only possible strategy for you is to place all your main website files at your root directory, then place all you include files in children directories... and place them wisely ;) I was already able to achieve this in the past, but it was a complete headache to be wiser than the wiser wizard ^^ Sorry not being able to help more.

Comment: Thanks @AlexLaforge.  I was getting the idea that I couldn't do it in the structure I have.. I just wanted clarification that it couldn't be done (going up one level or accessing it via an absolute path) before I went down the road of changing over 200 files to fix this.  ;-)

Comment: Probably a little late, but load 'em all up into Notepad++ (select all, right-click, and edit with Notepad++), do a search and replace, and click the "Replace All in All Opened Documents" button. Except for downloading and uploading it takes less than a minute. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual paths instead. You have to specify the full path but it gets the job done. I also tried configuring the web site to enable parent paths but that didn't work either.